# Google bigquery data transfer service header issue

Tags: google-bigquery

When I transfer a csv file from cloud storage to BigQuery, it adds an additional header row for each transfer. So my schedule query is failed due to additional header row. Can anyone please assist how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#setting_up_a_cloud_storage_transfer to setup your transfer, then change `header row to skip` to 1
[image]